# A matrix inside a table

Tags: tables, matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables)

I am trying to insert a matrix inside a table, and I am looking for a good way to do this. Usually when I write matrices in equations, I use array environment, so I naively defined an array inside tabular, and it sort of works. The only problem is that the matrix itself seems to take up a huge amount of space inside the cell. An example is

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{EKF} & \textbf{UKF}\\
\hline
$Q = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0.1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.1 \end{array}\right]$ & $Q = left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0.01 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.01  \end{array}\right]$\\
\hline
$R = 5 \times 10^{-3}$ & $R = 5 \times 10^{-5}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Is there any way to increase the spacing in the cell containing the matrix without that matrix taking up all the space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of possibilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}


\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{4}

 \begin{tabular}{|*2{>{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}}c|}}
\hline
\textbf{EKF} & \textbf{UKF}\\
\hline
$Q = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0.1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0.1 \end{array}\right]$ & $Q = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0.01 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.01  \end{array}\right]$\\
\hline
$R = 5 \times 10^{-3}$ & $R = 5 \times 10^{-5}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\bigskip


 \begin{tabular}{|*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.3\textwidth}|}}
\hline
\textbf{EKF} & \textbf{UKF}\\
\hline
\[Q = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0.1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0.1 \end{array}\right]\] & \[Q = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0.01 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.01  \end{array}\right]\]\\
\hline
\[R = 5 \times 10^{-3}\] & \[R = 5 \times 10^{-5}\]\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

`*{2}{c|}` just repeats `c|` or in general the second argument (`p{.3\textwidth}` in this case) that many times, that is standard latex, not requiring any package.

`>` is extended syntax from the `array` package (which is part of the core LaTeX distribution) which inserts declarations into every cell in that column, in this case `\centering\arraybackslash` the `\centering` inserts `\centering` into each of the p column cells so the text centres. Unfortunately `\centering` locally defines `\\` to be a newline command for centred text so it no longer ends a table row, `\arraybackslash` re-asserts the tabular/array definition of `\\`.

Answer (score 10):

I think you should eliminate the vertical rules and use [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) with vertical spacing controlled after each `\\`.

[image]

Furthermore, as egreg commented, you get better matrix spacing with a amsmath's `bmatrix` environment:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
\toprule
\textbf{EKF} & \textbf{UKF}\\
\midrule\\
\addlinespace[-2ex]
$Q = \begin{bmatrix}  0.1 & 0 \\ 0 &  0.1 \end{bmatrix}$ &
$Q = \begin{bmatrix} 0.01 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.01 \end{bmatrix}$\\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
$R = 5 \times 10^{-3}$ & $R = 5 \times 10^{-5}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```