# Change tabular row height including a matrix

Tags: tables, arrays

I am looking for a way, to change the height of a row in a tabular environment (or **evenly** add space at the top and bottom) but without changing the size of an included matrix.

If I use `\renewcommand{arraystretch}{1.5}` (which works perfectly in any other case) unfortunately also changes the size of my matrix. See MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\2\\3 
\end{pmatrix}$&2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\2\\3 
\end{pmatrix}$&2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me the following output:

[image]
and 
[image]

But I actually want something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please have a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/121799). Unfortunately the accepted answer may not be the most useful one.

Comment: And [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94308/121799) may be more directly applicable.

Answer (score 2):

The `cellspace` package is done for that: you can define  *minimal* vertical spacings at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|Sc|c|}\hline
$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{pmatrix}$&2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works but it gives me 2 warnings: `Command \@startpbox has changed. Check if current package is valid.`  (and same with `\@endpbox`) You have an idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: @chris/ I have the latest version (1.7, from 8/12/2018), and have the same warnings. Maybe this is linked to a recent change in `array` (dated 30/12/2018). I'll send a message to the package author.